# Mouse hover only working on last item

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, hover

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('mainCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var status = document.getElementById('status');
var click = document.getElementById('click');
var hover = document.getElementById('hover');

canvas.style.backgroundColor = 'red';

var mouseX;
var mouseY;

var item1 = new item('item1', ctx);
item1.drawItem(50, 50);
var item2 = new item('item2', ctx);
item2.drawItem(150, 200);
var item3 = new item('item3', ctx);
item3.drawItem(200, 250);

var items = [item1, item2, item3];

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveHandler, false);
canvas.addEventListener('click', mouseClickHandler, false);

function mouseMoveHandler(event) {
  mouseX = event.clientX - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left;
  mouseY = event.clientY - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
   if (mouseX > items[i].x & mouseY > items[i].y &
    mouseX < items[i].x + items[i].width & mouseY < items[i].y + items[i].height) {
    hover.innerHTML = items[i].name;
   } else {
    hover.innerHTML = 'No';
   }
  }
}

function mouseClickHandler(event) {
  click.innerHTML = mouseX + ' | ' + mouseY;
}

function item(name, ctx) {
  this.x = undefined;
  this.y = undefined;
  this.width = 50;
  this.height = 50;
  this.name = name;

  this.drawItem = function(x, y) {
    ctx.fillRect(this.x = x, this.y = y, this.width, this.height);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='canvas'>
  <canvas id='mainCanvas' width='500' height='300'></canvas>
</div>
<p id='click'>0 | 0</p>
<p id='hover'>No</p>
```

**What I'm trying to accomplish:**

When the mouse hovers each square (or item) in the canvas, I want the name of the square (assigned as the first parameter when creating each item) to display as the hover element.

**What I'm getting:**

It somewhat works, but only with the last square. Whenever I hover over any other square that isn't the last one, the 'hover' element does not display the name of the square the mouse is over. I even created and added a new item to the 'items' array and it worked with the new one, but not with the others.

Comment: Please show the associated HTML and CSS right here so that we can replicate your issue. When you link to 3rd party sites, there is a chance that the link will become broken over time and then your question won't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the for loop keeps running after you find a hit. Lets say you mouse item2. Your code will work and display 'item2'. Then the loop goes to the next step and checks if you hover over item3. You don't, so the code displays 'no'.

The solution is to stop the loop once you have a hit

```
    if (mouseX > items[i].x & 
       mouseY > items[i].y &
       mouseX < items[i].x + items[i].width & 
       mouseY < items[i].y + items[i].height
    ) {
        hover.innerHTML = items[i].name;
        break;
    } else {
        hover.innerHTML = 'No';
    }
```